# Systemwide USB keyboard hook

Tags: c++, winapi, usb, driver, wdk

im looking into the WDK at the moment to see how i would be able to make a systemwide keyboard hook on USB keyboards ( and a specific ID ).

What i want to be able to is to filter the keystrokes coming in from that specific USB keyboard (USB HID/keyboard), and be able to send that to a specific application/process only.

Ive seen examples of applications that has to be running that can do that in combination of rawinput and a hook, but i would like it to be systemwide and not demanding an application to run.

I can find examples that makes it quite easy to do with a PS2 keyboard, but when it comes to the USB it starts to look very different.

anyone could suggest me the correct model it has to be based on, and even better examples of how it would be possible to do that ?

and something that would work from XP/windows7 to Windows10 also.

Comment: I am not convinced, that filtering global keyboard input and sending it to a specific application is a viable solution to interacting with barcode scanners. It's awkward, that this specific question (and proposed solution) keeps popping up. As an aside, a driver cannot direct input to a specific application. It doesn't even know about applications.

Comment: yes ok it cant send to applications, maybe it could paas it to a file, and have a service maybe feeding it into applications ? theres alot of examples of PS2 hooks, but when it comes to barcode scanners or rf readers USB, theres very little unless its a one application thing.

Comment: keyboard hooks are independent of the interface on that the keyboard is attached because keyboard hooks are 'behind' or downstream of the driver, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms644985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  "The keyboard input can come from the local keyboard driver or from calls to the keybd_event function. If the input comes from a call to keybd_event, the input was "injected"."

Comment: @ralfhtp: A low-level keyboard hook, however, can identify injected input. It's provided as part of the *flags* field in the [KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644967.aspx).

Comment: you can program this like a keylogger. a process that notifies keystrokes and then forwards the data via a pipe or another IPC mechanism to your other program. on http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/lounge/27569/ is an example using hooks

Comment: seraphimsan on http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/lounge/27569/ is so funny ...

Comment: but it has to filter a specific USB device only, it would be easy (at least in the old days) to do it with std keyboard. the USB adds to the complexity as i read it.

Comment: i think not. the keyboard driver is registered as the unique keyboard driver and the hook attaches to the driver. as there is only one keyboard driver this is distinct "The user presses the key and from keyboard device driver sends signals to user's application. And we hook the the stream of that." https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/194729/Keyboard-Hooking-In-Kernel